# Laravel Validation for "other than" array of values

Tags: laravel

So I have a field called "featured_order" which consists of a single integer number (1, 2, 3, ...) OR null. Let's say I have this data:

| Name | Featured Order |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | null |
| D | 3 |

What I'd like to do is during UPDATE, a user can successfully update if there is no change in the "featured_order" or the change is different than any "featured_order" value from other data except null.

Using the example data before, let's say I want to update data B, which has the "featured_order" of 2. I'll successfully update the data if the "featured_order" value is either 2, OR other than 1 and 3 (so 4, 5, 6, ... is good).

However, if I put either 1 or 3, it'll trigger validation error because it must be a different number than what's already inside the table (except itself).

I have tried several things, like creating a variable that contains the array of "featured_order" that is not null and not itself using this code:

```
$data = Model::where('featured_order', '!=', null)
             ->where('featured_order', '!=', $this->featured_order)
             ->pluck('featured_order');
```

and then I use not_in validation like this:

```
'featured_order' => "not_in:$data"
```

But it didn't work. I also tried using unique validation like this code below, but it also didn't work:

```
'featured_order' => "unique:products_and_solutions,featured_order,$data"
```

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: have you tried `"not_in:".implode(',',$data)` ? or `Rule::notIn($data),`

Comment: @N69S Sorry for late reply, but yes I have tried that and it doesn't work. If I hard code it like "not_in:1,2" then it the validation works. But if I use $data it doesn't even though I have check via dd() that the values are in array, which then I implode to make a comma separated string

Comment: Did you change it to array before imploding it ? `"not_in:".implode(',',$data->toArray())`